# Validate the results of a form element and return multiple options that can be selected (i.e. address validation)

Tags: botframework

I’m looking for an example to do something like the following:

- Bot asks for full address
- Bot calls out to Bing Spatial services and gets back one or more addresses.
- If there is more than one response the bot lists those responses and lets the user pick the correct one.

Right now I’m doing that in a FormBuilder’s Confirm for that specific class property (this allows me only to pick the "best" address):

```
        return new FormBuilder<ReportImpairment>()
                ...
                .Field(nameof(Address))
                .Confirm(async (state) =>
                {
                    var addresses = await AddressHelper.ParseUserInput(state.Address);  // calls Bing Spatial Services to Geo Code address
                    var oldAddr = "";
                    var newAddr = "";
                    if (addresses.resourceSets.Any())
                    {
                        if (addresses.resourceSets.First().resources.Any())
                        {
                            oldAddr = state.Address;
                            newAddr = addresses.resourceSets.First().resources.First().address.formattedAddress;
                            state.Address = newAddr;
                        }
                    }
                    return new PromptAttribute($"The address you entered was **{oldAddr}**, we did an address validation and found the following address **{ newAddr }**; is this correct?  If not type **back** and re-enter your address, if it looks good enter **yes**");
                })
```

Comment: Do you want to do it in FormFlow or are you open to other approaches?

Comment: You could use the Validation callback on a field - if Bing Spatial only returns one result for the address, then you would return a valid response, if there is more than one result you can return an invalid response with a message to say "I found the following possible addresses - please try entering one of them instead [address 1] or [address 2]" which should then give you sufficient information to select the correct one.